# Series ID: Sanderson-esque trilogy(?) about religious figures

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for what I think was a trilogy of books similar in style to Brandon Sanderson's. (I originally thought they were by him, but looking at his bibliography nothing seems to match on a surface level.) Confusion is possibly due to the cover which I remember being similar to the white relief Sanderson book covers (below). Details are very hazy as I must have read it around 2015 give or take a few years. What I remember:

- Main characters with powers granted through some kind of connection to a god or belief
- Conflict between at least two factions based on differing beliefs/allegiances
- At one point a character can fly or travel very quickly, and tries escaping danger by going to an isolated forest community, possibly their point of origin
- A character trying to lay low in a city, evading some kind of authority force, but being discovered and the ensuing battle causing a lot of damage may be what led to the point above
- Read from a school library, so must have been somewhat YA suitable
- Books were a medium length novel, maybe ~300 pages
- Definitely not the Mistborn or Stormlight series

Sorry details are so vague, will try to improve if anything comes to me

[image]

Comment: Can you try re-inserting the image?  It's not in a format I can view.  Or link to another source, like [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?32726).

Comment: Do you remember how big the books were? Some of this sounds like it would align with Sanderson’s Stormlight books. They’re substantial doorstops and aimed at an older audience than the Mistborn books, but wouldn’t be out of place in a school library.

Comment: Similar length to mistborn I think, it's definitely not the stormlight archive, I'll update the q with that.

Comment: Just checking--those are the UK covers. Where did you read the trilogy?

Comment: UK school library